# jQuery: "$(this).next().next()" works, but "$(this).next('.div')" does not

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, this

Okay, I am trying to get this set of information to hide individually.

This works:

```js
$(".arrow").click(function() {
  $(this).next().next().slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<img class="arrow" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40">
<H2>More Information</H2>

<div class="box">
  <h2>Bibendum Magna Lorem</h2>
  <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
</div>

<img class="arrow" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40">
<H2>A Second Group of Information</H2>

<div class="box">
  <h2>Bibendum Magna Lorem</h2>
  <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This doesn't:

```js
$(".arrow").click(function() {
  $(this).next('.box').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<img class="arrow" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40">
<H2>More Information</H2>

<div class="box">
  <h2>Bibendum Magna Lorem</h2>
  <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
</div>

<img class="arrow" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40">
<H2>A Second Group of Information</H2>

<div class="box">
  <h2>Bibendum Magna Lorem</h2>
  <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

What is happening that makes the second option not work? I've been at it for days and can't bloody figure it out! I appreciate your input!

Comment: FYI, the indent of your HTML makes it look like you have parent/child relationships between elements that aren't actually there (kind of a misleading way to show the HTML).

Comment: ah, yeah, that makes sense, totally my bad! I'm fairly new to this so i'm still getting used to everything. Thanks for pointing that you!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**The Problem**

If you look at the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/next/) for `.next(selector)`, it does not "find" the next sibling that matches the selector.  Rather, it looks at JUST the next sibling and ONLY returns that element if it matches the selector which is not what you want.

Here's what the doc for `.next()` says:

> Description: Get the immediately following sibling of each element in
>   the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves
>   the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

So, you can see that `.next(".box")` will look at the `h2` element that immediately follows your `.arrow` element (that's the next sibling element) and then compare that to the `.box` selector and since they don't match, it will return an empty jQuery object.

---

**A Solution Using .nextAll()**

If you want the next sibling that matches a selector, you can use this:

```
$(this).nextAll(".box").eq(0).slideToggle();
```

This finds all the siblings that follow that match the selector and then extracts just the first one.

---

**Create Your Own .findNext() Method**

I've so often wondered why jQuery doesn't have a method for this that I've made one myself:

```
// get the next sibling that matches the selector
// only processes the first item in the passed in jQuery object
// designed to return a jQuery object containing 0 or 1 DOM elements
jQuery.fn.findNext = function(selector) {
    return this.eq(0).nextAll(selector).eq(0);
}
```

And, then you would just use:

```
$(this).findNext(".box").slideToggle();
```

---

**Option: Add More Structure to the HTML to Make Things Simpler and More Flexible**

FYI, a common approach to problems like this is to put a containing div around each set of DOM elements like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="arrow" src="images/navigation/arrowright.png">
    <H2>More Information</H2>
    <div class="box">
            <h2>Bibendum Magna Lorem</h2>
            <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
     <img class="arrow" src="images/navigation/arrowright.png">
     <H2>A Second Group of Information</H2>
     <div class="box">
            <h2>Bibendum Magna Lorem</h2>
            <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
     </div>    
</div>
```

Then, you can use code that is a little less sensitive to exact positioning of elements:

```
$(".arrow").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".container").find(".box").slideToggle();
});
```

This goes up to the containing and common parent using `.closest()` and then uses `.find()` to find the  `.box` element in that group.

Comment: more expressive: `$(this).nextAll(".box").first().slideToggle();`

Comment: "More Structure to the HTML to Make Things Simpler and More Flexible"