# How to add jQuery show/hide function inside forloop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop

I want to add a jQuery **show/hide** function to my website. The [usual](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp) show/hide function works but mine is a bit more complex than the usual one.

The "hide div" and the the div I want to hide/show on click are inside a for-loop and there are tons of divs with this names. I can add specific ids for each div (programmatically) but I couldn't add this name inside JavaScript programmatically: I have to add them manually.

**This is the piece of code I want to add the function:**

```
{% for facet in facets %}
    <div class="block-title"> {{ facet.name }} <div id="hide">HIDE</div></div>
        <ul class="term-list">
            {% for stat in stats %}
                <li class="term-item>{{ stat.name }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

**And this is the show/hide function:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
        $(".term-list").hide();
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $(".term-list").show();
    });
});
</script>
```

When I click on the hide button, it hides each and every `.term-list` divs as expected.

**I tried two methods but couldn't be successful:**

1. I added a number to `#hide` and `.term-list` divs (with forloop), it becomes: `#hide1` and `.term-list1`, `#hide2` and `.term-list2`, ... But I couldn't add a working for-loop to JavaScript code.
2. I tried to hide only the following (next) `.term-list div` when click to `#hide` but the `next()` and `nextAll()` [functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30281166/jquery-this-this-next-next-works-but-this-next-div-does-not) didn't work.

So, **what should I do to add jQuery show/hide function inside this for-loop?**

Comment: Just use a partial selector for the javascript. If you have `#hide1` and so on, select the specific ID by using a `$('[id^=hide]')` and match it to event.target (the element being clicked)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't repeat IDs in a page, they are unique by definition. Use classes instead

Then use a traverse to locate associated list

```
$(".hide").click(function(){
    // "this" is element event occurred on
    $(this).closest('.block-title').next().hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `$(this)` jQuery object to select element to **hide** or **show** (and you have to change id attribute `hide` to class because you should have only one element with one id on webpage).

After change id attributte to class:

```
var elTerms = null;
$('.hide').click(function(){
  elTerms = $(this).closest('div').find('ul.term-list');
  if (elTerms.is(':visible')) {
    elTerms.hide();
  } else {
    elTerms.show();
  };
});
```

Comment: Alfred - thanks for edit. On phone there is not so much ways to format post